# Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data

Tags: php, dom, xpath, xquery

any idea why this kind of error appears? at first i thought it because of the Whitespaces, but after i worked with the whitespaces. it still gives me this error :(

here's my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<produk>
    <softSpec>
        <style>android iphone</style>
        <comm>  
            <simSvas>1</simSvas>
            <dataScon>
                <gprs>1</gprs>
                <wap>1</wap>
            </dataScon>
            <message>
                <sms>
                    <swr>1</swr>
                    <sin>1</sin>
                    <sout>1</sout>
                    <sdrf>1</sdrf>
                    <ssent>1</ssent>
                </sms>
                <mms>
                    <mwr>1</mwr>
                    <min>1</min>
                    <mout>1</mout>
                    <mdrf>1</mdrf>
                    <msent>1</msent> 
                    <groupSmms>1</groupSmms>
                    <mmsSchatSroom>1</mmsSchatSroom>
                    <commSbm>1</commSbm>
                </mms>
                <email>
                    <esent>0</esent>
                    <erecv>0</erecv>
                    <ein>0</ein>
                    <eout>0</eout>
                    <esent>0</esent> 
                    <edrft>0</edrft>
                    <eact>0</eact>
                </email>
            </message>
            <phonebook>
                <capacity>500</capacity>
                <searchCon>1</searchCon>
                <add>1</add>
                <save>1</save>
                <dial>1</dial>
                <grupNum>1</grupNum>
                <captiveChk>1</captiveChk>
            </phonebook>
            <call>
                <simShist>
                    <sim1>1</sim1>
                    <sim2>1</sim2>
                </simShist>
                <dialSupSip>1</dialSupSip>
                <callSgrup>0</callSgrup>
                <setScallSid>0</setScallSid>
                <callSdiv>1</callSdiv>
                <callSbar>1</callSbar>
                <callShold>1</callShold>
                <callSredial>1</callSredial>
                <callSfee>1</callSfee>
                <handsfree>1</handsfree>
                <cdial>1</cdial>
                <crecv>1</crecv>
                <callSrec></callSrec>
            </call>
        </comm>
        <multimedia>
            <cam>
                <swScam>1</swScam>
                <subScam>1</subScam>
                <mainScam>1</mainScam>
                <capt>1</capt>
                <zoom>1</zoom>
                <contras>1</contras>
                <save>1</save>
                <flash>0</flash>
                <setStoSwpp>1</setStoSwpp>
                <viewSpic>1</viewSpic>
                <wbSconf>1</wbSconf>
                <contSphoto>1</contSphoto>
                <exposureScomp>1</exposureScomp>
                <effectSset>1</effectSset>
            </cam>
            <video>
                <vidSform>
                    <mp4>1</mp4>
                    <trigp>1</trigp>
                    <avi>1</avi>
                    <rmvb>1</rmvb>
                    <kingSmov>1</kingSmov>
                </vidSform>
                <vidSrec>1</vidSrec>
                <swScam>1</swScam>
                <vidSfcam>0</vidSfcam>
                <vidSrcam>1</vidSrcam>
                <vidSzoom>1</vidSzoom>
                <contras>1</contras>
                <save>
                    <phone>1</phone>
                    <mmc>1</mmc>
                </save>
                <vidSplay>1</vidSplay>
                <vidSdisp>1</vidSdisp>
                <adjSvol>1</adjSvol>
                <addSvid>
                    <fromScard>1</fromScard>
                    <fromSphone>1</fromSphone>
                </addSvid>
                <vidSapp>1</vidSapp>
            </video>
            <audio>
                <audSform>
                    <mp3>1</mp3>
                    <wav>1</wav>
                    <midi>1</midi>
                </audSform>
                <play>1</play>
                <playlist>1</playlist>
                <playSsett>1</playSsett>
                <backSsound>1</backSsound>
                <btoothSaudSout>0</btoothSaudSout>
                <adjSvol>1</adjSvol>
                <add>
                        <fromScard>1</fromScard>
                        <fromSphone>1</fromSphone>
                    </add>
                <radio>1</radio>
                <radioSmenu>
                    <radSplay>1</radSplay>
                    <adjSvol>1</adjSvol>
                    <selectSfeq>1</selectSfeq>
                    <saveSfreq>0</saveSfreq>
                    <searchSfreq>1</searchSfreq>
                    <record>0</record>
                    <save>
                        <card>0</card>
                        <phone>0</phone>
                    </save>
                </radioSmenu>
                <soundSrec>1</soundSrec>
                <soundSrecSmenu>
                    <record>1</record>
                    <play>1</play>
                    <save>
                        <card>1</card>
                        <phone>1</phone>
                    </save>
                </soundSrecSmenu>                   
            </audio>
            <imaging>
                <imSviewer>1</imSviewer>
                <imSviewerSmenu>
                    <rotate>1</rotate>
                    <zoom>1</zoom>
                    <slide>1</slide>
                    <setSwpp>1</setSwpp>
                    <send>
                        <viaSbtooth>1</viaSbtooth>
                        <viaSmms>1</viaSmms>
                    </send>
                    <edit>1</edit>
                    <detail>1</detail>
                </imSviewerSmenu>
                <photoEditor>1</photoEditor>
                <photoSeditorSmenu>
                    <autoSresize>0</autoSresize>
                </photoSeditorSmenu>
            </imaging>
            <anotherSmfunc>
                <tv>1</tv>
                <games>1</games>
                <gps>0</gps>
                <keypadSlock>1</keypadSlock>
            </anotherSmfunc>
        </multimedia>
        <service>
            <simSserv>
                <stkSsimS1>1</stkSsimS1>
                <stkSsimS2>1</stkSsimS2>
                <browsing>1</browsing>
            </simSserv>
            <chat>1</chat>
            <java>0</java>
            <opera>0</opera>
            <mSoffc>0</mSoffc>
            <fbSsc>0</fbSsc>
            <pimoSsc>0</pimoSsc>
            <tpulsaSsc>0</tpulsaSsc>
        </service>
        <tools>
            <btooth>
                <onSoff>1</onSoff>
                <send>1</send>
                <recv>1</recv>
                <a2dp>0</a2dp>
            </btooth>
            <cald>1</cald>
            <calc>1</calc>
            <task>0</task>
            <alarm>1</alarm>
            <wSclock>1</wSclock>
            <uSconvrt>1</uSconvrt>
            <currSconv>1</currSconv>
            <healthSman>1</healthSman>
            <ebookSread>1</ebookSread>
            <swatch>0</swatch>
            <notes>1</notes>
            <codeStable>1</codeStable>
            <updownloadSpbook>0</updownloadSpbook>
            <usrSprof>1</usrSprof>
            <handwritting>1</handwritting>
        </tools>
        <sett>
            <fileSman>
                <intSmem>1</intSmem>
                <extSmem>1</extSmem>
                <rwmrmov>1</rwmrmov>
                <format>1</format>
            </fileSman>
            <disp>
                <wpp>1</wpp>
                <ssaver>1</ssaver>
                <ponSdisp>1</ponSdisp>
                <poffSdisp>1</poffSdisp>
                <showSownSnum>0</showSownSnum>
            </disp>
            <pSsett>
                <schSpowSon>1</schSpowSon>
                <inSlang>
                    <eng>1</eng> 
                    <stroke>1</stroke>
                    <piyin>1</piyin>
                    <french>0</french>
                    <german>0</german>
                    <spain>0</spain>
                    <russian>0</russian>
                    <indonesian>1</indonesian>
                    <portugis>0</portugis>
                    <turkish>0</turkish>
                    <persian>0</persian>
                    <italia>0</italia>
                </inSlang>
                <lang>
                    <eng>1</eng>
                    <ind>0</ind>
                    <china>1</china>
                    <french>0</french>
                    <german>0</german>
                    <spain>0</spain>
                    <russian>0</russian>
                    <indonesian>0</indonesian>
                    <portugis>0</portugis>
                    <turkish>0</turkish>
                    <persian>0</persian>
                    <italia>0</italia>
                </lang>
                <timeSdate>1</timeSdate>
                <prefSin>0</prefSin>
                <greetStext>0</greetStext>
                <dedicSkey>0</dedicSkey>
                <autoSupdateStime>1</autoSupdateStime>
                <uartSsett>0</uartSsett>                
            </pSsett>
            <sSoth>
                <soundSsett>1</soundSsett>
                <soundSsettSopt>
                    <audSeff>1</audSeff>
                    <bassSench>0</bassSench>
                </soundSsettSopt>
                <dualSsimSsw>0</dualSsimSsw>
                <dualSsimSsett>0</dualSsimSsett>
                <penScall>0</penScall>
                <netwSsett>0</netwSsett>
                <secSsett>0</secSsett>
                <restSsett>0</restSsett>
            </sSoth>
            <miscSsett>
                <sensSapp>
                    <wallSshuff>0</wallSshuff>
                    <mp3Sshuff>0</mp3Sshuff>
                    <phoneSshake>0</phoneSshake>
                    <shakeStoSreadSsms>0</shakeStoSreadSsms>
                    <fmSchsSshake>0</fmSchsSshake>
                    <revrseSphoneSmute>0</revrseSphoneSmute>
                    <doubleSknockSmute>0</doubleSknockSmute>
                </sensSapp>
                <voiceaidSsett>
                    <enginSsett>0</enginSsett>
                    <rSinScall>0</rSinScall>
                    <rSinSmess>0</rSinSmess>
                    <rStimeSonSidle>0</rStimeSonSidle>
                    <rStimeSperShour>0</rStimeSperShour>
                    <rSmenu>0</rSmenu>
                    <rSmesg>0</rSmesg>
                    <rScharge>0</rScharge>
                    <rSdial>0</rSdial>
                    <vol>0</vol>
                    <rate>0</rate>
                    <pith>0</pith>
                </voiceaidSsett>
                <wapp>
                    <wappSform>
                        <gif>1</gif>
                        <bmp>1</bmp>
                        <jpg>1</jpg>
                    </wappSform>
                    <wallScust>1</wallScust>
                    <dynamicSscreensaver>0</dynamicSscreensaver>
                </wapp>
            </miscSsett>
        </sett>     
        <miscSfunc>
            <ani>
                <pSonSlogo>1</pSonSlogo>
                <pSoffSlogo>1</pSoffSlogo>
            </ani>
            <ring> 
                <default>1</default>
                <ringSform>
                    <mp3>1</mp3>
                    <midi>1</midi>
                    <wav>1</wav>
                </ringSform>
                <backSringSforScall>1</backSringSforScall>
                <ringSedit>1</ringSedit>
            </ring>
            <vibSfeedback>
                <touchSscr>1</touchSscr>
                <dialSnum>1</dialSnum>
            </vibSfeedback>
        </miscSfunc>
    </softSpec>

</produk>
```

and here's my php code

```
<?php
//buat matching database
$existdb="http://localhost:8080/exist/testing";

function URLopen($url){
    $dh = fopen("$url",'r');
    $result= fread($dh,8192); //fread buat baca filenyeah
    return $result; 
}

$codeparameter = $existdb.'/retrieve_codetable.xql';
$returnedpcode=URLopen($codeparameter);
$fileparameter = $existdb.'/coba.xql';
$returnedpfile=URLopen($fileparameter);
//echo $returnedpfile;

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($returnedpcode); 
$dom1=new DOMDocument;
$dom1->loadXML($returnedpfile); 


$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom1);
$query = '/produk//*';
$entries=$xpath->query($query);

foreach($entries as $entry){
    echo "[" . $entry->nodeName."]";
}


?>
```

Comment: You're only showing one xml document, but your php code references two.

Comment: yes yes.. but the other file working fine.. it doesn't take effect  :)

Comment: Hmm strange... This error comes when you don't close a complexType element, but the XML you copied here is valid... (Maybe you have unicode whitespace characters in that.)

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you only load 8k of data here `$result= fread($dh,8192);`.

Answer (score 0):

OK I searched for your problem. Premature end of data seems to be the result of the `fread()` function.

Try to rewrite your URLopen() function a bit:

```
function URLopen($url)
{
    $dh = fopen($url,'r');
    $result = '';
    while (!feof($dh))
    {
        $result .= fread($dh, 8192); // Put this in a while loop.
    }
    return $result; 
}
```

In your script only files up to 8kb will be loaded. Maybe one of your XML files were larger.